# Is there a surjective holomorphic function $f : \mathbb{D} \rightarrow \mathbb{C} $

Tags: complex-analysis

$\mathbb{D}$ is the open unit disk. I know $f$ can't be injective, which leads $f^{-1}$ exist and bounded, by Liouville Theorem. What about other cases?

Comment: Hint: do you know how to define a surjective holomorphic function from $\mathbb{D}$ to the upper half plane?

Comment: You can actually do a surjective $2 \to 1$ function (preimage a point is generally two points) either using the hint above or by squaring the Koebe function $z/(1-z)^2$ so with $f(z)=z^2/(1-z)^4$

Comment: @Conrad Why not an official answer?